# How to calculate the maximum concurrency on ssh reverse tunneling

Tags: ssh, concurrency, ssh-tunnel, tunnel, tunneling

For my personal development environment I have setup a reverse tunnele via ssh between a raspberry pi as the server which hosts my applications and a 5$ DO droplet instance with nginx and certbot to act as the publicly available ip point of my application:

---

**Like below:**

Raspberry Pi (origin server containing my in development application code for my flask and nodejs projects) === ssh reverse tunneling ===> DO instance with certbot and nginx

---

For tunneling itself I am using a command like the one below:

`ssh -R 5000:localhost:5000 doadminuser@digitaloceanip`

**Desired Next Step:**

I was thinking of using the same technology for a real WP website like this, so in other word I have the WordPress website hosted on my Raspberry Pi and then my domain being linked to my DO instance and whenever someone comes to my domain, the traffice gets redirected to the local Raspberry Pi via the reverse tunneling:

---

Request comes to *domain.com* linked to digital ocean instance => nginx on the DO instance reverse proxies the traffic to the local port 5000 (the port which is being reverese tunneled to from my local pi) => the reverse tunnel sends the traffic to the local pi and the application to get the desired outcome and return it to the one who asked data from the domain

---

**My Question:**

What type of metrics should I pay attention to and what tips and tricks can I use to increase number of concurrent traffic to setup more or less similar to the desired setup above?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: It's not very clear from your question, whether you (a) have flask behind nginx on your DO droplet, and you're using an ssh tunnel to access this from your Pi, or (b) you're somehow using the Pi as the origin server, with traffic reaching it through an ssh tunnel from the nginx instance on your DO droplet.  I'd advise re-reading your question and editing it to clarify this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your attention @v25, I have rephrased the question, please let me know if it is still requires improvements